# How to keep PHP 5.5 but use 5.4 (CodeIgniter deprecated)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, debian

I have a dedicated server running with ISPConfig 3.
It came under Debian 7 (officially PHP 5.4).
I have upgraded it to PHP 5.5.

However, I didn't realize that CodeIgniter needs the mysql driver to run... Therefore, my website doesn't work anymore.

So either I find a way to use PHP 5.4 only on a website (without affecting the others running under PHP 5.5) or I find a way to "upgrade" CodeIgniter so it doesn't use the deprecated mysql extension anymore.

Comment: Deprecated != Removed, It should work just fine on PHP 5.5 & throw an E_DEPRECATED error (You can suppress the error). but in general it's better if you use mysqli driver instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can make this simple change to `config/database.php`

Change

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
```

to:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
```

As CI uses a database abstraction layer, this should be transarent.