# upgrading from php 5.3 to php 5.5 showing connection error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

1. I was using php 5.3 version and migrated to php 5.5 current version
2. I am using below line to connect to database
3. It is showing below error

> mysql_connect($db[$active_group]['hostname'],$db[$active_group]['username'],$db[$active_group]['password']);
>
> Message: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will
>   be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead, Filename: config/routes.php

4 I browsed and try to keep like this

> mysqlli_connect($db[$active_group]['hostname'],$db[$active_group]['username'],$db[$active_group]['password']);
>
> Call to undefined function mysqlli_connect()

How can i fix this !!!!!!!

Comment: its  **mysqli_connect()** not  mysqlli_connect()

Comment: mysqlli_connect should be mysqli_connect (one L to much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may find this link a liitle helpful..........

Currently mostly many MySQL connections in PHP use this construct:
PHP:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('dbname', $link);
```

The way with MySQLi would be like this:
PHP:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
```

To run database queries is also simple and nearly identical with the old way:
PHP:

```
// Old
mysql_query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table`', $link);
// New
mysqli_query($link, 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table`');
```

http://www.bestwebframeworks.com/tutorials/php/36/solve-mysql-extension-is-deprecated--will-be-removed-in-the-future-of-php/

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the database driver: [How to keep PHP 5.5 but use 5.4 (CodeIgniter deprecated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970217/how-to-keep-php-5-5-but-use-5-4-codeigniter-depreciated)

What i see from you're code is a double l in mysqlli_connect.

Make sure that mysqli is installed on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
mysqlli_connect($db[$active_group]['hostname'],$db[$active_group]['username'],$db[$active_group]['password']);
```

with

```
mysqli_connect($db[$active_group]['hostname'],$db[$active_group]['username'],$db[$active_group]['password']);
```

It's a spelling error (`mysqlli_connect()` should be `mysqli_connect()`).